# maven release-plugin usage in non-interactive mode

Tags: maven, release

I’m confused as to how the version number in a pom file and the system properties like -DdevelopmentVersion=2.0-SNAPSHOT and -DreleaseVersion=1.2 work when maven is run in non-interactive mode.

When I run `mvn –B release:prepare –Dtag=1.2 -DdevelopmentVersion=2.0-SNAPSHOT -DreleaseVersion=1.2` for a pom.xml with `<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>` and `<packaging>jar</packaging>` the resulting jar file uses the pom version number not the command line version, i.e xxx-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar .

Is this the expected behaviour and if so what is the point of specifying the versions on the command line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found my mistake:
Before running the example release:prepare in my question I had carried out a dryRun i.e. using the option`-DdryRun=true` . 
This had created a release.properties file which was be used by subsequent release:prepare commands until it was cleaned up using release:clean

Answer (score 3):

You should be aware that the [`release:prepare`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html) is the first part of the release process. Afterwards you need to give [`release:perform`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/perform-release.html) which will checkout the created tag from version control and start the build for the artfiact whcih will be really released.